# 0% usage on udev (/dev) partition

Tags: udev

On two Ubuntu VMs I have a filesystem under the name `udev` with a size of 7.4G and 0% used. It's mounted on `/dev`.

Just wondering if this low usage is normal behavior.

Comment: Yes, this is normal.  See:  https://superuser.com/a/675664/440143

Comment: @Terrance Great. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal for the `/dev` mount to be used at 0%.  Also, great information about the `/dev` mount can be found at https://superuser.com/a/675664/440143

---

*This is from the above link. Please give credit to the original author.*

> `udev` is not a partition on a permanent hard drive. It is a [RAM disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk). As such it does not consume any capacity of a permanent hard
>   drive (except part of swap when the system is short on RAM).
>
> ### RAM disks and /dev in Linux
>
> Ubuntu as many modern Linux distributions uses [`devtmpfs`](http://lwn.net/Articles/331818/) file system for the `/dev` directory. The directory contain [special
>   (device) files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) which are just interfaces to device drivers.
>   `devtmpfs` is a just special instance of [`tmpfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs). The `/dev`
>   directory is an essential part of the Unix-like directory structure.
>   If you delete it the system will stop functioning.
>
> You can notice that in Ubuntu `tmpfs` is also being mounted on `/run`
>   and its subdirectories. On some other systems it could also be mount
>   at `/tmp`.
>
> ### Your questions
>
> 1. The space assignment is the default setting. By default `tmpfs` file systems are limited to 50 % of your RAM capacity. (Do you have 64
>      GB of RAM?) The number is really just a limit because the `tmpfs` file
>      systems do occupy only the space which is needed to store the files
>      and for the `/dev` directory the required space is very small. The
>      occupied capacity in your (an my) case is few KB.
> 2. You cannot influence the `tmpfs` sizes by partitioning because they are not stored on physical drives. Removing it is not possible at
>      all without substantial changes to the system. You can make the size
>      limit lower: `sudo mount -o remount,size=1G /dev` but this will only
>      change the limit but not the actual occupied RAM space.
>
> ### Solution to your problem
>
> Your solution is to repartition the drive and make `/dev/sda1` larger (easier if repartitioning is possible) or to add new partitions
>   and, mount them to the appropriate directories and move the existing
>   files there to free the root (`/`) file system.

---

Hope this helps!